# php convert string to date time "21 December 2012 - 03:45 PM"

Tags: php, mysql, datetime-format

i am using bootstrap date time picker to pick date and time . its giving me output
"21 December 2012 - 03:45 PM" now i want to store it on MySQL database my problem is how can i store this string to MySQL data column (data type = date time).

here i using this code but its not working

```
$s = '21 December 2012 - 03:45 PM';

$date = strtotime($s);
echo date('d/M/Y:H:i:s', $date);
```

i want to store this string to mysql datbase in  date time format. extract same string on sql query run

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input string format from that datepicker has like that:

```
21 December 2012 - 03:45 PM
```

You need to convert the format first that is applicable for your `DATETIME` field which is:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

From PHP, you could use the `DateTime` class. Provide the format that you have in your datepicker:

```
$s = '21 December 2012 - 03:45 PM'; // input from date picker
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d F Y - G:i a', $s);
$insert_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $insert_date;
// rest of your mysql insertion codes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for write to mysql:

```
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $date )
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL expects DateTime fields to be past to it for storage in this format

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

So change this statement to

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
```

And of course you have to wrap that string in quote in the SQL statement like this

```
$s = '21 December 2012 - 03:45 PM';

$a_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($s));

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (the_date) VALUES ('$a_date')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use epoch values instead of human readable date strings. Do all your stuff using UTC epoch values and convert into human readable strings only when you have to show the date to the user (add locale, etc..etc..).

Answer (score 0):

when you do `strtotime($s);`
so in your view you can `<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$row['date']) ?>`